# how to compute expectation of $R_1R_2$ when $R_1$ and $R_2$ are independent?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

Here's my problem:

> Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be independent random variables, each with the
>   exponential density $f(x) = e^{-x}, x \ge 0; f(x) = 0, x \lt 0$ Then,
>   find the expectation of $R_1R_2$

I know that if $R_1$ and $R_2$ are independent, their probability distribution function equals $f_{12}(x_1, x_2) = f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2)$ when $f_1(x_1)$ and $f_2(x_2)$ are the respective probability distribution functions. But is there a more direct way of computing $f_{12}(x_1, x_2)$ than that by more fundamental fact(or definition)? Or is this the definition of independency of random variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the following argument: $ER_1R_2=E(E(R_1R_2)|R_2))=E(R_2E(R_1|R_2))=ER_2(ER_1)=ER_2 (1)=(1)(1)=1$.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what kind of theorems you used here? Since I never saw a similar argument I'm lost.

Comment: The first step is called the towering property of conditional expectation. The second step uses the fact that $R_2$ act as  constant when conditioned on $R_2$ so it can be pulled out of the conidtional expectation. The third step is where independence is used.  @queueoverflow